# How to display JSON result in aspx?

Tags: asp.net, json

I  have a [JSON link](http://demo.easydataharvest.com/martin/ajax_search_product.php?pn=CEDM7001&man=Central%20Semiconductor%20Corp)
 and want show record in my website page by using this type of link with different parameter value.

Comment: Are you asking how to make an HTTP call to some URL? And how to pass different query parameters? The first part can be answered by googling for ".NET HTTP Request".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

```
 string a = "{\"data\":[{\"ID\":1,\"MANUFACTURER\":\"Central Semiconductor Corp\",\"PRODUCT_NAME\":\"CEDM7001\",\"REPTYPE\":\"similar\"},{\"ID\":2,\"MANUFACTURER\":\"Central Semiconductor Corp\",\"PRODUCT_NAME\":\"CEDM7001E\",\"REPTYPE\":\"similar\"},{\"ID\":3,\"MANUFACTURER\":\"Central Semiconductor Corp\",\"PRODUCT_NAME\":\"SSM3K16CT\",\"REPTYPE\":\"direct\"}]}";
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic b = js.DeserializeObject(a);
    dynamic[] c = b["data"];
    for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
    {
        string ID =Convert.ToString(c[i]["ID"]);
        string MANUFACTURER = Convert.ToString(c[i]["MANUFACTURER"]);
        string PRODUCT_NAME = Convert.ToString(c[i]["PRODUCT_NAME"]);
        string REPTYPE = Convert.ToString(c[i]["REPTYPE"]);
    }
```

Comment: The OP isn't asking about deserialization. Besides, JavaScriptSerializer is obsolete and never meant to be a good JSon deserializer